# git update-index --assume-unchanged not working as expected when merging

Tags: git, git-merge, gitignore

I updated index of some files to untrack them from git. Unfortunately, those files are still in circulation on some commits by teammates.

This means that if I pull changes, even though I've ignored those files on my side, the files will still cause conflicts and some unlink errors. The only way I can resolve this is to unset update index with --no-assume-unchanged, and re-commit all the files to complete the merge. This creates a vicious loop where the files are back in circulation again.

How can I work around this problem without forcing the entire team to re-clone their repository?

Answer (score 1):

You aren’t being very clear on what you are ultimately trying to achieve, and it seems to me that there is a very good chance that this is more a social and a coordination issue rather than a problem with `assume-unchanged`.

If your end goal is remove the files from circulation (to end the “vicious loop” as you state it), you should remove them with `git rm`, make sure the build is correct and there are no test or staging errors and commit and publish (ie push) the result into an authoritative development branch, such as *master* for instance. When your team members will pull the branch, they will have to deal with the fact that the files are gone, and merge the fact into their development branches. This is of course more of a communication and a coordination problem rather than a git problem, and there will be no need to re-clone repositories.

However, if your end goal is to have the files permanently ignored in *your* development working-tree, notwithstanding any fetches and pulls, then `assume-unchanged` is the wrong  tool for the job, because its documentation explicitly requires you to manually handle a merge commit. That’s of course the graceful and correct way to proceed – after all the file **is** in the repository, and you need to be aware of it changing.

Comment: The end goal is to have the files permanently ignored in everyone's development tree.

Comment: Then follow the part "... you should remove them with `git rm` ..."

Comment: @mockinterface - this will not work in cases when the file is needed for the first time when developers clone the project, but should not be updated with developer's local changes. One example - Visual Studio _references.js file with autoregeneration turned on causes absolute paths in some situations (files linked from other VS projects). This file is required when cloning the project, so it cannot be just removed. But it should not be committed back.